# Applescript error when trying to get file list from folder

Tags: applescript

I'm having trouble getting AppleScript to read a list of files from a folder without receiving the error message "Can't get every file from folder XXX"

```
set targetfolder to ("DICTAPHONE:DSS_FLDA:")
tell application "Finder"
 set fileselection to every file in targetfolder
endtell
```

This worked flawlessly before upgrading to Mavericks. Paths are correct. I tried it with a different folder on my startup disk and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `folder targetfolder` instead of `targetfolder`:

```
set targetfolder to ("Macintosh HD:Library:Desktop Pictures")
tell application "Finder"
    files of (folder targetfolder)
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the information:

```
set targetfolder to (path to desktop as alias)
tell application "Finder"
    set fileselection to get the name of every file of targetfolder
end tell
```